# How to install Nvidia GTX1660Ti in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, additional-drivers

I recently bought a new laptop, Acer Predator Helios 300. And I'm deciding to install Ubuntu on it. But I heard that Nvidia doesn't work with Linux really well. So I'm asking how to install Nvidia GTX1660Ti GPU driver on Ubuntu 20.04. I am looking forward for your answers.

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247220/ubuntu-20-04-installing-nvidia-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247220/ubuntu-20-04-installing-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu already installed, and the GPU is not properly working, or are you only planning on installing it? There are proprietary NVidia drivers that can be installed during installation which work well in the majority of cases, just remember checking "Install additional proprietary hardware drivers" or something like that during installation.

Comment: I am still planning on installing Ubuntu in it. But I thought to ask here first. Regarding the "Install additional proprietary hardware drivers", does it support the latest Nvidia drivers?

Comment: It should install the latest stable drivers available at the time of installation. There are always ways to update them afterwards. But since the NVidia driver management in Ubuntu can be a little shaky, I would just let the installer choose the right driver and then not touch it anymore if everything works.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 default appears to install the Nouveau driver. The NVIDIA driver is needed for serious neural net work.

Comment: Did you go ahead and install Ubuntu? Did you install the nvidia driver successfully? How?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an intergrated GPU on it? If yes, then there is a good chance you will get a headache. However, the straight answer to the question in title is `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450`