# Not showing NVIDIA GPU in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hp, nvidia-prime

I have HP 15-r244TX laptop(N15V-GM-S-A2 GPU NVIDIA Graphics Chipset) NVIDIA GeForce 820M
I run every command but still GPU not showing.
lspci | egrep -i “vga|display|3d”
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
only output.

I also tried this but nothing happen

[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247220/ubuntu-20-04-installing-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: You turned off secure boot, you checked your UEFI Settings/BIOS for video settings that disable the discrete video hardware,... What does ubuntu-drivers output? Is the nvidia module listed from the lsmod output?  Any errors or fuller descriptions of what happens will help us make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: secure boot already off. I have checked BIOS but noting there related to video settings that disable the discrete video hardware. Is the nvidia module listed from the lsmod output? nothing just showing Intel