# How can I properly setup and use my NVIDIA card on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have a Dell Inspiron 7706 2n1 with a NVIDIA GeForce MX350 and a 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7.

Right now I'm using Intel Integrated Graphics but I want to be able to switch to my NVIDIA card when using certain apps. I've looked up online what to do but nothing seems to help me. I've tried doing `prime-run` but it's not installed. When I do `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo` to test gpu switching, I get this back in return:

```
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
 Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
 Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
 Value in failed request:  0x0
 Serial number of failed request:  50
 Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

What can I do?

Things that might help

```
❯ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: Dell Device 09df
--
2b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce MX350] (rev a1)
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
2c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

```
❯ modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

```
❯ prime-select query
intel
```

```
/etc/modprobe.d
❯ grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia-drm
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia-modeset
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia-drm off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia-modeset off
```

```
❯ find /usr/lib/modules -name nvidia.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-470/nvidia.ko
```

```
❯ modinfo nvidia | grep version
version:        470.129.06
srcversion:     EB51CE03E42F9639560C463
vermagic:       5.15.0-41-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

```
❯ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

Comment: Add the output of xrandr --listproviders   Unless the source and sink are reversed (i.e. sink is the Nvidia card), you probably don't need the __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia  
I have noticed that the ordering is inconsistent in Ubuntu 22.04, so sometimes I need it, sometimes I don't.  The only blacklist of nvidia should be the nvidiafb. That and options nvidia-drm modeset=1 should be the only nvidia in that directory.  See what alias off got you!

Comment: @ubfan1 ```❯ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting```

Comment: also im using Kubuntu 20.04 lts

Comment: Please answer questions by editing your original posting, where code formatting is available.  I don't know where all that blacklisting and alias code came from, but none of it is needed.  Clean it all out, and start again. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247220/ubuntu-20-04-installing-nvidia-drivers
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04  No PPA's have been needed for awhile, the standard repos are pretty up to date.

Comment: i would what im asking for realistically is how can i properly set up prime offloading using the proprietary nvidia drivers